# Struct in C, functions with structs

Tags: c, struct

I have this functions , and i am trying to search in an array in a struct. 
Now I cant understand where my mistake is, but I believe that is, at the part where function is defined, where I try convert the player country into lowercase.( which in the file holds names of country). when I run the program, and I enter the country name the program just stops and crashes after I enter the name i want to search for.

Anyone can help me? Thank you .

```
#define NAME_LENGTH 50
#define NUM_PLAYERS 200

struct player_champ
{
    char player_country[NAME_LENGTH];
};

int search_player_by_country( struct player_champ  ptr_player[] , char asked_name[NAME_LENGTH], int lines_got);   
int main (void)    
{
    struct player_champ  player_info[NUM_PLAYERS] = { { 0 } };
    char asked_country[NAME_LENGTH]= {0};

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter the name of the country you want to search for.\n\n>>>");
    fgets(asked_country, sizeof(asked_country)-1, stdin);
    asked_country[strlen(asked_country)-1] = '\0';
    search_player_by_country ( player_info, asked_country, num_lines_read);

    int search_player_by_country( struct player_champ ptr_player[] , char asked_country[NAME_LENGTH], int lines_got)
    {
        char temp_asked_country[NAME_LENGTH], temp_country_name[NAME_LENGTH];
        int i,k,z=0,j,counter=0;

        // there is a part of the code here that converts what user entered to lower case as well.

        for (i = 0 ; i < lines_got; i ++)
        {     
            k=0;

            /* while (ptr_player[i].player_country)
            {
                temp_country_name[j] = tolower (ptr_player.player_country);
                j++;
            }*/

            for (k = 0 ; k < lines_got; k ++)
            {
               temp_country_name[k] = tolower (ptr_player[k].player_country);
               k++;
            }
            temp_country_name[k] = '\0';

            if (strstr(temp_country_name, temp_asked_country) != NULL)
            {
               print_info( ptr_player[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Barmar, at this piece of code it doesn't, but in my program, I think it does because I call scanf and fgets multiply times.

Comment: `fflush` only has an effect on output streams, not input streams.

Comment: @Barmar, Okay I guess you are right. Do you have any idea, on why I am not doing it right the search function?

Comment: You didn't initialize ptr_player beyond setting it to empty in this code segment.

Comment: function `search_player_by_country` declaration, before `main` is malformed.

Comment: @abiessu how should I initialize the ptr_player?

Comment: @Kira , that was supposed to be the prototype, but i had erased some part of it, by mistake.

Comment: @user2512806 I dont  understand your pointe here.. temp_country_name[k] = tolower (ptr_player[k].player_country); temp_country_name[k] can hold a single character but you try to initialize it with a string i guess..

Comment: Where is num_lines_read set?

Comment: also you have nested function definition... mate that code needs house keeping.

Comment: @Jim num_lines_read is an int and is the number of lines that my fscanf reads from a file, it is 153 as value, it is another function part of the program, not shown here.

Comment: @AmarnathKrishnan, well thats where i think I am doing it wrong, because I dont know how to do that.

Comment: @Barmar: whether `fflush(stdin)` does anything useful depends on the platform.  On Unix-based (POSIX) systems, it does nothing.  On Windows, [`fflush(stdin)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) is defined to clear pending input (more or less the service performed by [`tcflush()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcflush.html) under POSIX when the standard input is a terminal).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler every time I read one of your comments I just end up saying _mmm oh... duuude!_. Many Thanks for taking the time

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes you are right, I took commented out and, my code runs weird now. Because on my big program, there are scanf, which appear before fgets, and carry a new line character, so fflush, is useful on my case. and I use a Windows

Answer (score 3):

This code is totally wrong:

```
    for (k = 0 ; k < lines_got; k ++)
    {
        temp_country_name[k] = tolower (ptr_player[k].player_country);
        k++;
    }
```

1. You're incrementing `k` twice -- in the loop header and in the body.
2. The target of the assignment is a single character in the `temp_country_name` string, but the parameter to `tolower()` is an entire string. Aren't you getting a warning from the compiler saying that the parameter to `tolower()` is the wrong type (it expects a `char`, you're giving it a `char*`)?
3. You're already iterating over lines in the outer loop using `i`. This loop should just iterate over characters.

Try this:

```
    for (k = 0 ; ptr_player[i].player_country[k]; k ++)
    {
        temp_country_name[k] = tolower (ptr_player[i].player_country[k]);
    }
```

`ptr_player[i]` is the player from element `i` in the array. `player_country[k]` is character `k` in that string. So `ptr_player[i].player_country[k]` is the k'th character in the i'th player's country.

There are probably other problems in your code, I haven't tried to find them.

Comment: passing argument 1 of 'tolower' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|

this is the warning I get, Yeah you are right about that k++, but if you see there is a while loop commented out, I was trying to use a while loop before.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me, what does:ptr_player[i].player_country[k] do in each places it occurs.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: @user2512806 ptr_player[i] points to a player at an instance and ptr_player[i].player_country[k] will point to a players country char sequence.. assumiing you have a player user1 and he is from INDIA.. than ptr_player[0] will point to user1 and ptr_player[0].player_country[0] will point to first character of user1 's country..  (i.e) ptr_player[0].player_country[0] should point to ' I ', ptr_player[0].player_country[1] should point to ' N ' and it goes like this..

Comment: @AmarnathKrishnan Yeah, I do understand that part, but why it needs to be on the for loop, inside the parenthesis?

Comment: In the `for` loop header it's just testing whether it has reached the `\0` that ends the string.